# How to read the Webdriver screenshot directory?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, directory, webdriver

I want to read the path of the saved screenshot to a variable.

After

`browser.save_screenshot('Test.png')`

I want to save the directory of this file to a variable `file_path`.

For e.g. `print(file_path)` should give the output as `D:\Test.png`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `save_screenshot` saves relative to your current working directory, assuming you pass in a relative file path. You can get your current working directory with `os.getcwd()` and store *that* instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the user @That1guy explained it, assuming that you are just saving the file with the code `browser.save_screenshot('Test.png')` then this means that the image will be saved relatively, i.e. the exact location in which your python file is based.

Therefore, to get the absolute CWD(currrent working directory), you can do so by importing the `os` module and via doing either

```
import os 
file_path= os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```

or

```
import os
file_path= os.getcwd()
```